Is there a way to view the BitLocker recovery password in linux (using a valid password)?
I have a Windows 10 bootable drive with Bitlocker encryption enabled. The PC was accidentally unplugged from the wall power, and since then when starting Windows, it asks for the Bitlocker password, reboots, and then asks for a recovery password, which I deleted a long time ago.
When I boot into WinPE environment it asks for a password, unlocks the drive but then says it's corrupted, while showing the drive icon without the capacity indicator.
However, when I boot into Ubuntu, it opens the drive fine with the password, both using dislocker and the default tool that the Nautilus file manager uses and the name of which I do not know.
Is there a way to view or recreate the 48-digit numerical recovery password from Linux?
Is there a repair tool that can fix whatever Bitlocker thinks is broken?

I believe you mean recovery password. A BitLocker recovery key is a binary blob that is copied to a file, and is typically only used in environments that disallow how the recovery password is stored.

I mean the digits-only numerical key that you can print or save as PDF when you setting up the Bitlocker. This key has a GUID-like identifier associated with it. Maybe it's called a password, but it is definetly used for a recovery and matches /([0-9]{5}-)+/

Also if you didn't save it, decrypt and reencrypt the drive.

I've checked and in my native language BitLocker calls it a key, while in English it is indeed a password, so thanks for all the corrections. Regarding the reencryption - if no other solutions found I'll buy another hard drive and copy all the files using Ubuntu to reinstall Windows and put everything back. But is there a way to reencrypt the partition from Linux? Because as I wrote, no copy of Windows can "see the data" currently.

There should not be a need to "reinstall Windows" if the drive is decrypted. You said you can unlock the drive on linux using the "password". Do that, decrypt the drive, then restart into Windows, which will work 100% due to BitLocker is no longer enabled or present.
